# Cannot execute stored procedure: 'One of the specified inputs is invalid.'

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I'm developing an API using Node.js, Express.js, and Azure DocumentDB. I'm able to successfully register a stored procedure with the following:

```
var documentdb = require('documentdb').DocumentClient;
var client = new documentdb(/* endpoint URL */, { "masterKey": /* master key */ });
var dbLink = /* db self link */

var test = {
  id: 'test',
  body: function () {
    __.response.setBody('Hello world.');
  }
};

client.upsertStoredProcedure(dbLink, test, function (err, res) {
  // save self link and rid to stored procedure object
  test.link = res._self;
  test.link = res._rid;
});
```

However, when I try to execute the stored procedure with this code:

```
client.executeStoredProcedure(test.link, function (err, res) {
  console.log(err || res);
});
```

I get a 400 Bad Request error: Encountered exception while executing function. One of the specified inputs is invalid.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have implemented several REST APIs on top of DocumentDB with node-restify (similar to express.js), I plugged your sproc into my framework and called it like you do here and I can't duplicate the issue. I get the correct response back 'Hello world.' Is it possible that the error is not from the executeStoredProcedure call but rather has something to do with the express.js API side?

Comment: BTW, what's the project? work/hobby/experiment? There seem to be few people trying to do what you and I are doing.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone It's kind of a unique project. I'm a linguist, and linguistics has a data problem. We don't have good central databases where linguists can share their data with each other. We have a lot of OS-specific programs, most of which are based on XML or proprietary formats. So me and some others at UC Santa Barbara are trying to take advantage of modern web technologies to fix this, defining a JSON schema for [interlinear glosses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlinear_gloss) and an API for managing linguistic data. It's very preliminary, but we're excited about its potential.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Let me know if you want to swap stories/design ideas. I really like node-restify over using express. I lean heavily on sprocs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*@dwheib figured out the issue on a [separate thread](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/thewindowsazureproductsite/documentdb_programming_stored_procedures_triggers_and_udfs/#comment-2339814111) - reposting here for everyones benefit.*

The issue was a missing trailing backslash in the database self-link (`test.link`).